# How to get containerId or container Name in a springBoot app running in AWS ECS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I have an spring-boot java application (as docker container), running in AWS ECS cluster . So I have a scheduler job that gets scheduled by each of the containers in the cluster, but I want to log the container name or id which schedules the job to hold a reference of which container has completed and to have a trace of different functions invoked within the container.  Which api shold i look into and is it possible to get the id from the container?

Answer (score 2):

You should query the ECS task metadata endpoint. The endpoint is exposed to your task via the `ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI` environment variable. This is documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint-v3.html).